# Django PasswordInput

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using PasswordInput, for an attribute that is optional.

### models.py

```
password = models.CharField(_('Site Password'), max_length=128,
    blank=True, null=True)
```

### forms.py

```
from django.forms import PasswordInput

...

class Meta:
    model = ...
    widgets = {
        'password': PasswordInput(),
    }
```

Which works as expected. However using this widget means there is no way to clear this input, once the password has been set once!

I was hoping to have something like the AdminFileWidget, where there is an option to clear the image/file by selecting the 'clear' checkbox.

Other option is to add an additional 'clear_password' field to the ModelForm.

```
clear_password = forms.BooleanField(label=_('Clear'), initial=False,
                                    required=False)
```

And clear the password on *save* method:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    ...

    if self.cleaned_data['clear_password']:
        obj.password = None
    else:
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        obj.password = make_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
```

And this works too. But I was hoping a more cleaner solution ..

I had a look at django.forms.widgets.ClearableFileInput .. but it's way too complex for a newbie like me :-(.

Any help will be appreciated. Many Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need a new compound widget.

Comment: What's a 'compound widget'? I have lot to learn .. could you please point me in the right direction.. quick google search returned nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You could clear the value of the form by passing a null value to the value attribute.

Something like that :

```
from django.forms import PasswordInput
from models import YourModel

password = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'value': ''})

class Meta:
    model = YourModel
```

Comment: I'm unsure how this solves my problem. I still can't clear the password field .. once it's been set once. But thanks for the suggestions. Appreciate it.